# What happens when Frog picks up a golden weapon?

Tags: nuclear-throne

To play as Frog, a character needs to have the golden frog pistol stored as their alternate weapon, and start a run with it.

If, for example, Fish had the golden frog pistol then picked up a golden machine gun, the machine gun would be stored as Fish's alternate weapon after going through a level ending portal. If Frog goes through a portal with a golden weapon other than the golden frog pistol, will this replace Fish's alternate weapon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Seems to be when Frog goes through a portal with a golden weapon, it stores the weapon for Frog, but the original character will still have the Golden Frog Pistol.

To test this, I started a co-op round with Frog (Steroids with GFP) and Horror with a golden shotgun.

[image: Co-op with Frog and Horror]

Had Horror replace his weapons so Frog could replace the GFP with a golden shotgun. Went through a portal and got the "Golden Shotgun Stored" message.

[image: Went through portal with Frog, stored golden shotgun]

Checked Steroids in the character menu only to find that he still has the GFP stored.

[image: Golden Frog Pistol not replaced]